# shared_ptr, unique_ptr, ownership, Am I overdoing it in this particular case?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr

I work on graphics applications and have been using shared & unique pointers essentially because it handles memory deallocation for me (aka as a convenience) which is probably bad (if that's the reason why I use them).

I read the answer to a question on Stackoverflow recently that mentioned that according to B. Stroustrup, unique/shared ptrs should generally not be used and that arguments should be passed by value instead.

I have a case in graphics for which I think using shared_ptr makes sense but I'd like to know from experts (I am not C++ experts) if I am over doing/thinking it and if so what they would be doing instead (to conform to C++ recommendations and for efficiency)

I will take a general problem that occurs in Rendering/Ray-Tracing. In this particular problem we have a pool of objects (we will use triangles for this explanation) and a structure which for the simplicity of the explanation we will refer to as regular 3D grid. Let's say that at some point we need to insert the triangles into the grid: what that means is that we need to check of the bounding volume of each inserted triangle overlaps any of the cells from the grid, and it does, then each overlapped cell needs to keep a pointer/reference to that triangle (for later use). A triangle may overlap more than 1 cell, so it can be referenced multiples times by several cells (you see where I am going with the `shared_ptr` here).

Note that outside of the grid structure, we don't need the pool of triangles (so technically the object that owns the pool of triangle here, is the grid or more precisely the grid's cells).

```
class Grid
{
    struct Cell
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Triangle>> triList; 
    };
    void insert(triangle*& tri_)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<const Triangle> tri = tri_;
        for (each cell overlapped by tri) {
            // compute cell index
            uint32_t i = ...
            cells[i].triList.push_back(tri);
        }
    }
    Cell cells[RES * RES * RES];
};

void createPoolOfTrianglesAndInsertIntoGrid()
{
    Grid grid;
    uint32_t maxTris = 32;
    Triangle* tris = new Triangles[maxTris];
    // process the triangles
    ...
    // now insert into grid
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < maxTris; ++i) {
        // use placement new
        Triangle* tri = new (&tris[i]) Triangle;
        grid.insert(tri);
    }
    // no need to delete tris here ... it should be done by 
    // the grid when we go out of this function's scope
}
```

It sounds complicated but my motivation behind this design is to follow Stroustrup's recommendation. In this case the function `createPoolOfTrianglesAndInsertIntoGrid` doesn't owned the triangles, it's the cells of the grid that do. So I allocate the memory in the function `createPoolOfTrianglesAndInsertIntoGrid` because this is where I need to create the triangles, and I then use the placement new method to get a pointer to each triangle in that pool which I can then pass to the grid `insert` method (I defer memory management of that object to that method). In there, it converts the triangle into a `shared_ptr` and cells can now share a "reference" to it (using `shared_ptr`).

I wanted to know if to your opinion this was going in the right direction, or if this appears completely wrong, both in terms of implementation and in terms of possible loss of efficiency (I allocate a pool of memory, then use the new placement to create a temp triangle, which I then pass on to the grid insert method, then convert to shared_ptr, ...)

I am trying to both learn, and improve my code and hope you can provide valuable professional feedback.

EDIT: basically I am trying to find the right approach to that problem + I will try to provide later some modifications based on your comments

Comment: You are constructing the triangles in `tris` *twice*. Once in the first allocation, and again when you do placement new in the loop. The last construction will recreate the element in `tris`, causing all previous modifications you have done on the object to be lost. If you want to pass a pointer to an element in the array `tris` just pass `&tris[i]`. This of course requires you to save a pointer to the array, so you can `delete[]` it at a later point. Something you need to do *anyway*.

Comment: how big/complicated is a Triangle? If it's 10 or 20 doubles then you're certainly better off copying it.

Comment: @Richard, yes it's true but there could be millions of them ...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: beware of assumptions on what's happening in this code as it is not compilable (a dynamic array is assigned to a single instance, no function parameters) .  user18490: can you tell me why the placement new is done (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) because that should only be used to construct already existing memory as if it was allocated with new and in this case the memory is already constructed?

Comment: @user18490 copying a shared_ptr is unlikely to be much cheaper than copying a Triangle. Iterating over iterm addressed by shared_ptr will be much slower than iterating over a vector of objects.

Comment: @stefaanv yes sorry I am trying to correct my mistakes in the code (and I will try to make a compilable version). My idea with the placement new operator was to break down the pool of triangles into individual triangles that I could then pass individually to the `insert` method.

Comment: A thing of "ownership". Who does own your objects? Usually it's good to have the objects who delete the memory also be the ones who allocate them. Allocating them in one function and then letting them being deleted else where is a good possibility of memory leaks. Also Unique_ptr are usually a good way to enforce and indicate ownership. They are also not that expensive performance wise compared to shared_ptr

Comment: @Hayt in this particular case I the grid cells own the triangles but I wanted to create a pool of triangles outside of the Grid itself (because I may need to set them which is not necessarily something the Grid class  should be responsible for.

Comment: I mean it's not wrong but as a design/code style improvement suggestion it would be nice to have memory alocation/deallocation encapsuled inside the class so outside functions don't need to know about it.

Comment: I don't have the time to read this in detail and write an answer at the moment, but one thing that I want to mention is that `shared_ptr` is very much meant for multi-threaded contexts. Most of the time when you encounter it in a single-threaded context, what you should really be doing is thinking more carefully about ownership and using something like `unique_ptr` (or the object itself). So keep that in mind.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to hold vector of pointers to Triangles and get rid of raw allocation and placement new?

Comment: @user18490: `Triangle* tris = new Triangles[maxTris];` already give you an array of Triangles, so placement new adds nothing, but can cause problems because the constructor is called twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like your `Grid` owns the triangles. I am assuming the triangles are relatively light (3-5 dimensions?).

I would think something like this might suit. I am using a *container* in the `Grid` to take ownership of the triangles **by value**. The *container* will delete the triangles when the `Grid` goes out of scope.

Then each `Cell` simply uses raw pointers to keep track of which triangles it references. The `Cell`s don't own the triangles they simply hold pointers to the triangles that are owned by the `Grid`.

```
class Grid
{
    struct Cell
    {
        std::vector<Triangle*> triList; // non owning
    };

    void insert(Triangle tri) // pass by value
    {
        tris.push_back(tri); // Grid owns this by value

        for(each cell overlapped by tri) {
            // compute cell index
            uint32_t i = ...

            cells[i].triList.push_back(&tris.back());
        }
    }

    // Use a deque because it won't re-allocate when adding
    // new elements to the end
    std::deque<Triangle> tris; // elements owned by value

   Cell cells[RES * RES * RES]; // point to owned elements
};

void createPoolOfTrianglesAndInsertIntoGrid()
{
    Grid grid; // owns the triangles (by value)

    uint32_t maxTris = 32;

    std::vector<Triangle> tris(maxTris);
    // process the triangles
    // ...
    // now insert into grid
    for(auto tri: tris)
        grid.insert(tri);
    }

    // no need to delete tris here ... it should be done by
    // the grid when we go out of this function's scope
}
```

**NOTE:** I use a `std::deque` to store the triangles by value in the `Grid`. That's because it won't ever reallocate its internal memory when adding new triangles. If you used a `std::vector` here your raw pointers would end up dangling when the `std::vector` resized itself.

**Alternatively:**

Given that it looks like you build all your triangles in your function and then pass all of them into `Grid`, why do that one at a time? You could pass the whole container in in one go. If you do this using *move semantics* you won't even have to copy anything:

```
class Grid
{
    struct Cell
    {
        std::vector<Triangle*> triList; // non owning
    };

    // Accept the entire container in-tack
    // (no reallocations allowed after this point)
    void insert(std::vector<Triangle> tris) // pass by value (able to move in)
    {
        //
        for(auto& tri: tris)
        {
            for(each cell overlapped by tri) {
                // compute cell index
                uint32_t i = ...

                cells[i].triList.push_back(&tri);
            }
        }
    }

    // Using a vector so it MUST NOT be resized after
    // Cells have been pointed to its elements!!!
    std::vector<Triangle> tris; // elements owned by value
    Cell cells[RES * RES * RES]; // point to owned elements
};

void createPoolOfTrianglesAndInsertIntoGrid()
{
    Grid grid; // owns the triangles (by value)

    uint32_t maxTris = 32;

    // Build the triangles into
    std::vector<Triangle> tris(maxTris);
    // process the triangles
    // ...
    // now insert into grid
    grid.insert(std::move(tris)); // move the whole darn container (very efficient)

    // no need to delete tris here ... it should be done by
    // the grid when we go out of this function's scope
}
```

**NOTE:** Now I used a `std::vector` because you are not adding triangles one by one after they arrive in `Grid`. But you MUST make sure that *inside* `Grid` the owning `std::vector is not resized.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks so yes I am over doing it. The problem I see is that if I have millions of triangles, then when all triangles will be inserted the triangles will be stored twice in memory (once by `createPoolOfTrianglesAndInsertIntoGrid` and once by the Grid). Of course as soon as we go out of scope of `createPoolOfTrianglesAndInsertIntoGrid` a chunk of that memory will be freed but that can be critical. My attempt as to allocate the memory only once as much as possible for the triangle pool.

Comment: @user18490 Take a look at the second example, it allocates everything just once and passes the whole container into `Grid` using `std::move` (nothing gets copied, its fast and efficient).

Comment: I also think that the grid owns the tris. If you were to make the cells smaller, would it destroy the triangles? It seems to me that it *should* not.

Comment: One could argue both the grid and the cells own the tris, I think. But the cells are already owned by the grid, so it seems sufficient to make only the grid own the tris because the cells can't escape the grids lifetime

Answer (score 1):

Efficient memory allocation is a separate concern to object lifetime and object behaviour.

The mechanism to control allocation strategies is the `Allocator` in `std::vector<Type, Allocator>` and in `std::allocate_shared<Type, Allocator>`

It looks like you want to perform allocations from a pool.

Firstly, giving `Triangle` value semantics (i.e. not holding a pointer to it) will allow `std::vector` to efficiently allocate blocks of memory already. It's allocation strategy assumes that more than one object will be needed. Under the covers it allocates blocks of memory and calls in-place constructors/destructors as appropriate.

If Triangle really needs to be a shared-handle (i.e. in terms of shared_ptr) then you can allocate the shared_ptr using a custom allocator.

Boost has a few examples of memory pool allocators.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are the only owners of the triangles, then you don't need a pool, just allocate Triangles as shared_ptr and insert them in the grid.  That way, all the triangles that are not owned by any cells anymore will be cleaned up.